# Error con C# y PosgreSQL conexión con la base de datos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Tengo este error al querer compilar el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «SELECT»'
```

Estuve buscando por el procedimiento en Postgresql pero es simple, no existe error.

```
DECLARE
RESULTADO TEXT;

BEGIN
SELECT NOMBRE INTO RESULTADO FROM public.cliente
ORDER BY idcliente ASC;
RETURN RESULTADO;
END;
```

De esta clase estoy sacando las conexiones DContable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//contableEntidad
using contableEntidad;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

namespace contableDatos
{
    public class DContable
    {

        public NpgsqlConnection Connections() {


            var stringConnection = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=contable1;Password=contable1;Database=contable";
            NpgsqlConnection SQLPostgres = new NpgsqlConnection(stringConnection);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringConnection))
            {

                try
                {

                    SQLPostgres = new NpgsqlConnection(stringConnection);
                    SQLPostgres.Open();


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    SQLPostgres.Close();
                }
            }

           // return SQLPostgres;

        }
        //Listar clientes
        public DataTable  Clientes() {


            //NpgsqlDataAdapter dataContable = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select listarclientes()", SQLPostgres);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select listarclientes()", Connections());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            NpgsqlDataAdapter Da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Da.Fill(Dt);
            return Dt;

        }

        //Listar 
        public  List<Paises> Paiseslist()
        {

            List<Paises> _lista = new List<Paises>();
            //NpgsqlDataAdapter dataContable = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select listarclientes()", SQLPostgres);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM pais", Connections());
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            NpgsqlDataAdapter Da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Da.Fill(Dt);
            //return Dt;
            while (_reader.Read()) {

                Paises lPais = new Paises();

                lPais.codigo = _reader.GetInt32(0);
                lPais.Denominacion = _reader.GetString(1);

            }
            return _lista;

        }






    }
 }
```

Comment: que es la clausula INTO en el SELECT? INTO  va en clausulas tipo INSERT no?

Comment: @Alfredo Paz En un procedimiento almacenado generalmente esos resultados son variables en una clausula into y de ahi en adelante ya puedes usarlos.¿A donde van a ir los resultados de tu query en store procedure? y como no le dices te marca error. La forma de decirle es la clausula into

Answer (score 0):

He probado a crear la función de esta forma

```
CREATE FUNCTION listarclientes() RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
SELECT nombre  FROM cliente
ORDER BY idcliente ASC
$$
language 'sql';
```

Y parece que funciona correctamente.